# Take a value in PHP page sent with a jQuery function

Tags: php, html

In this HTML page at the begin of the script I send the value of variable fin at the PHP page (http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?valore="+ fin). In this PHP page I tried to take the value of variable but I didn't have success.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Parsing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <script>
        var fin = "SAT000000002575";
        url = "http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?valore="+ fin,

        data = {
            get_param: 'value'
        };


        $.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {
             for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var lin = data[i]["Nr SAT"];
                $('body').append($('<p>').html('Numero Sat: <a href ="http://sat3.altervista.org/NuovoFile.html?id=' + lin + '">' + data[i]["Nr SAT"] + '</a>'));
                $('body').append($('<p>').html('Data Apertura: ' + data[i]["Data Apertura"]));
            }

        });

    </script>

        <body>
            <header>

            </header>


        </body>

    </html>
```

This is the PHP page where I send the variable and I can not take it.

```
<?php

// Sopprimo gli errori del php
error_reporting(0);

// Includo la libreria
require_once 'excel_reader2.php';



$file_handle = fopen("leggimi2.csv", "r");



//EDIT: Define an array to hold individual lines
$data = array();

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    //HERE I TAKE THE VALUE BUT IT DON'T CONTAIN NOTHING
    $myValue = $_GET["valore"];


    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    if ($line_of_text[0] == $myValue)
    {
        $arr = array('Nr SAT' => $line_of_text[0],'Data Apertura' => $line_of_text[13], 'Tipo Servizio' => $line_of_text[1], 'Stato SAT' => $line_of_text[2],'Marca Terminale' => $line_of_text[4], 'Modello Terminale' => $line_of_text[5], 'IMEI guasto' => $line_of_text[6],'IMEI consegnato' => $line_of_text[7],'Famiglia guasto' => $line_of_text[8],'Descrizione guasto' => $line_of_text[9] );

        //EDIT: Add the line to the array
        $data[] = $arr;
    }

}

//EDIT: Encode the array as a JSON array of line objects
echo json_encode($data);

//$myValue = isset($_GET['myValue']) ? $_GET['myValue'] : '';



fclose($file_handle);



?>
```

Comment: @DejaVu, yes, indeed :D

Comment: Help me, i dont understand the other page. What i have to do???

Answer (score 2):

Missing ';'

```
url = "http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?valore="+ fin,
```

try

```
url = "http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?valore="+ fin;
```